# WindowsCryptographicException: Keyset does not exist

Tags: asp.net-core, x509certificate, identityserver4

I want to create or obtain a certificate, create a pfx-file, load it and have IdentityServer use it. However, IdentityServer is not able to use my pfx.

How to successfully create a pfx and have IdentityServer use it?

I have an IdentityServer4 web solution running on localhost with ASP.Net Core. I am preparing the solution for production running on Azure, and is adding a certificate to the IdentityServer pipeline instead of the developer signing certificate.

Typically this means to swap code like

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
```

with

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddSigningCredential(cert)
```

where "cert" is an object instance of X509Certificate2 which has loaded a PFX-file containing the certificate (with public and private keys).

The certificate I am using is self signed and is created by following the steps on Ben Cull's Blog https://benjii.me/2017/06/creating-self-signed-certificate-identity-server-azure/

The certicate and private key is exported to a PFX-file in order for both public and private key to be contained in the file.

The loading of the PFX-file succeeds. The code for loading is

```
cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(Environment.ContentRootPath, "MyPfxFile.pfx"), "password-used-when-exporting-pfx");
```

The Pfx-file is located within the web project and is found and read into the X509Certificate object.

When inspecting the X509Certificate2 in Visual Studio the property HasPrivateKey return true, but the PrivateKey property resolves to an exception in the watcher.

```
'cert.PrivateKey' threw an exception of type 'Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException'
```

All other properties look sound and good in the watcher.

Also, when I execute the GetRSAPrivateKey in the Immediate Window method on the certificate object instance, it returns an exception.

```
cert.GetRSAPrivateKey()
'cert.GetRSAPrivateKey()' threw an exception of type 'Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146893798
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Keyset as registered is invalid"
    Source: "System.Security.Cryptography.Csp"
    StackTrace: "   at Internal.NativeCrypto.CapiHelper.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer)\r\n   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.get_SafeProvHandle()\r\n   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.get_SafeKeyHandle()\r\n   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 keySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize)\r\n   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(CspParameters parameters)\r\n   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.<>c.<GetRSAPrivateKey>b__61_0(CspParameters csp)\r\n   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.GetPrivateKey[T](Func`2 createCsp, Func`2 createCng)\r\n   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.GetRSAPrivateKey()\r\n   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificateExtensionsCommon.GetPrivateKey[T](X509Certificate2 certificate, Predicate`1 matchesConstraints)\r\n   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions.GetRSA
PrivateKey(X509Certificate2 certificate)"
    TargetSite: {System.Security.Cryptography.SafeProvHandle CreateProvHandle(System.Security.Cryptography.CspParameters, Boolean)}
```

I have tried loading the pfx-file with different settings for X509KeyStorageFlags, but the behaviour and exceptions are the same.

I have also tried to install the PFX into the Windows machine's certificate manager, and I am successfully loading it from there, but the same exceptions are thrown.

At last, when requesting an access token from IdentityServer, the same exception is thrown. I have pasted the exception trace below.

```
IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware:Critical: Unhandled exception: Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: Keyset as registered is invalid
   at Internal.NativeCrypto.CapiHelper.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.get_SafeProvHandle()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.get_SafeKeyHandle()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 keySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(CspParameters parameters)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.<>c.<GetRSAPrivateKey>b__61_0(CspParameters csp)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.GetPrivateKey[T](Func`2 createCsp, Func`2 createCng)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.GetRSAPrivateKey()
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificateExtensionsCommon.GetPrivateKey[T](X509Certificate2 certificate, Predicate`1 matchesConstraints)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions.GetRSAPrivateKey(X509Certificate2 certificate)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey.get_PrivateKey()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey.get_HasPrivateKey()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricSignatureProvider.HasPrivateKey(SecurityKey key)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricSignatureProvider..ctor(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean willCreateSignatures)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateSignatureProvider(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean willCreateSignatures)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateForSigning(SecurityKey key, String algorithm)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.CreateEncodedSignature(String input, SigningCredentials signingCredentials)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(SecurityToken token)
   at IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenCreationService.CreateJwtAsync(JwtSecurityToken jwt) in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\Services\DefaultTokenCreationService.cs:line 209
   at IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenCreationService.<CreateTokenAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\Services\DefaultTokenCreationService.cs:line 67
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenService.<CreateSecurityTokenAsync>d__9.MoveNext() in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\Services\DefaultTokenService.cs:line 210
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator.<CreateAccessTokenAsync>d__14.MoveNext() in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\ResponseHandling\TokenResponseGenerator.cs:line 313
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator.<ProcessAuthorizationCodeRequestAsync>d__10.MoveNext() in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\ResponseHandling\TokenResponseGenerator.cs:line 133
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator.<ProcessAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\ResponseHandling\TokenResponseGenerator.cs:line 88
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint.<ProcessTokenRequestAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\Endpoints\TokenEndpoint.cs:line 98
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint.<ProcessAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\Endpoints\TokenEndpoint.cs:line 70
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\Hosting\IdentityServerMiddleware.cs:line 54
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Message","time":"2018-10-17T09:19:34.1583055Z","tags":{"ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"HEBE","ai.operation.id":"d7c51fcd-421c862dd08fe813","ai.operation.parentId":"|d7c51fcd-421c862dd08fe813.","ai.operation.name":"POST /connect/token","ai.location.ip":"127.0.0.1","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.1.1","ai.internal.nodeName":"HEBE"},"data":{"baseType":"MessageData","baseData":{"ver":2,"message":"Unhandled exception: Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: Keyset as registered is invalid\r\n   at Internal.NativeCrypto.CapiHelper.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer)\r\n   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.get_SafeProvHandle()\r\n   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.get_SafeKeyHandle()\r\n   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 keySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize)\r\n   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(CspParameters parameters)\r\n   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.<>c.<GetRSAPrivateKey>b__61_0(CspParameters csp)\r\n   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.GetPrivateKey[T](Func`2 createCsp, Func`2 createCng)\r\n   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.GetRSAPrivateKey()\r\n   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificateExtensionsCommon.GetPrivateKey[T](X509Certificate2 certificate, Predicate`1 matchesConstraints)\r\n   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions.GetRSAPrivateKey(X509Certificate2 certificate)\r\n   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey.get_PrivateKey()\r\n   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey.get_HasPrivateKey()\r\n   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricSignatureProvider.HasPrivateKey(SecurityKey key)\r\n   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricSignatureProvider..ctor(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean willCreateSignatures)\r\n   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateSignatureProvider(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean willCreateSignatures)\r\n   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateForSigning(SecurityKey key, String algorithm)\r\n   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.CreateEncodedSignature(String input, SigningCredentials signingCredentials)\r\n   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(SecurityToken token)\r\n   at IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenCreationService.CreateJwtAsync(JwtSecurityToken jwt) in C:\\local\\identity\\server4\\IdentityServer4\\src\\IdentityServer4\\Services\\DefaultTokenCreationService.cs:line 209\r\n   at IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenCreationService.<CreateTokenAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\\local\\identity\\server4\\IdentityServer4\\src\\IdentityServer4\\Services\\DefaultTokenCreationService.cs:line 67\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenService.<CreateSecurityTokenAsync>d__9.MoveNext() in C:\\local\\identity\\server4\\IdentityServer4\\src\\IdentityServer4\\Services\\DefaultTokenService.cs:line 210\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator.<CreateAccessTokenAsync>d__14.MoveNext() in C:\\local\\identity\\server4\\IdentityServer4\\src\\IdentityServer4\\ResponseHandling\\TokenResponseGenerator.cs:line 313\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator.<ProcessAuthorizationCodeRequestAsync>d__10.MoveNext() in C:\\local\\identity\\server4\\IdentityServer4\\src\\IdentityServer4\\ResponseHandling\\TokenResponseGenerator.cs:line 133\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator.<ProcessAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\\local\\identity\\server4\\IdentityServer4\\src\\IdentityServer4\\ResponseHandling\\TokenResponseGenerator.cs:line 88\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint.<ProcessTokenRequestAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\\local\\identity\\server4\\IdentityServer4\\src\\IdentityServer4\\Endpoints\\TokenEndpoint.cs:line 98\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint.<ProcessAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\\local\\identity\\server4\\IdentityServer4\\src\\IdentityServer4\\Endpoints\\TokenEndpoint.cs:line 70\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\\local\\identity\\server4\\IdentityServer4\\src\\IdentityServer4\\Hosting\\IdentityServerMiddleware.cs:line 54","severityLevel":"Critical","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development","{OriginalFormat}":"Unhandled exception: {exception}","exception":"Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: Keyset as registered is invalid\r\n   at Internal.NativeCrypto.CapiHelper.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer)\r\n   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.get_SafeProvHandle()\r\n   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.get_SafeKeyHandle()\r\n   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 keySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize)\r\n   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(CspParameters parameters)\r\n   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.<>c.<GetRSAPrivateKey>b__61_0(CspParameters csp)\r\n   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.GetPrivateKey[T](Func`2 createCsp, Func`2 createCng)\r\n   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.GetRSAPrivateKey()\r\n   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificateExtensionsCommon.GetPrivateKey[T](X509Certificate2 certificate, Predicate`1 matchesConstraints)\r\n   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions.GetRSAPrivateKey(X509Certificate2 certificate)\r\n   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey.get_PrivateKey()\r\n   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey.get_HasPrivateKey()\r\n   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricSignatureProvider.HasPrivateKey(SecurityKey key)\r\n   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricSignatureProvider..ctor(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean willCreateSignatures)\r\n   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateSignatureProvider(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean willCreateSignatures)\r\n   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateForSigning(SecurityKey key, String algorithm)\r\n   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.CreateEncodedSignature(String input, SigningCredentials signingCredentials)\r\n   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(SecurityToken token)\r\n   at IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenCreationService.CreateJwtAsync(JwtSecurityToken jwt) in C:\\local\\identity\\server4\\IdentityServer4\\src\\IdentityServer4\\Services\\DefaultTokenCreationService.cs:line 209\r\n   at IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenCreationService.<CreateTokenAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\\local\\identity\\server4\\IdentityServer4\\src\\IdentityServer4\\Services\\DefaultTokenCreationService.cs:line 67\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenService.<CreateSecurityTokenAsync>d__9.MoveNext() in C:\\local\\identity\\server4\\IdentityServer4\\src\\IdentityServer4\\Services\\DefaultTokenService.cs:line 210\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator.<CreateAccessTokenAsync>d__14.MoveNext() in C:\\local\\identity\\server4\\IdentityServer4\\src\\IdentityServer4\\ResponseHandling\\TokenResponseGenerator.cs:line 313\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator.<ProcessAuthorizationCodeRequestAsync>d__10.MoveNext() in C:\\local\\identity\\server4\\IdentityServer4\\src\\IdentityServer4\\ResponseHandling\\TokenResponseGenerator.cs:line 133\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator.<ProcessAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\\local\\identity\\server4\\IdentityServer4\\src\\IdentityServer4\\ResponseHandling\\TokenResponseGenerator.cs:line 88\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint.<ProcessTokenRequestAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\\local\\identity\\server4\\IdentityServer4\\src\\IdentityServer4\\Endpoints\\TokenEndpoint.cs:line 98\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint.<ProcessAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\\local\\identity\\server4\\IdentityServer4\\src\\IdentityServer4\\Endpoints\\TokenEndpoint.cs:line 70\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\\local\\identity\\server4\\IdentityServer4\\src\\IdentityServer4\\Hosting\\IdentityServerMiddleware.cs:line 54","CategoryName":"IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware"}}}}
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware:Error: An unhandled exception has occurred: Keyset as registered is invalid

Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: Keyset as registered is invalid
   at Internal.NativeCrypto.CapiHelper.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.get_SafeProvHandle()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.get_SafeKeyHandle()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 keySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(CspParameters parameters)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.<>c.<GetRSAPrivateKey>b__61_0(CspParameters csp)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.GetPrivateKey[T](Func`2 createCsp, Func`2 createCng)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.GetRSAPrivateKey()
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificateExtensionsCommon.GetPrivateKey[T](X509Certificate2 certificate, Predicate`1 matchesConstraints)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions.GetRSAPrivateKey(X509Certificate2 certificate)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey.get_PrivateKey()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey.get_HasPrivateKey()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricSignatureProvider.HasPrivateKey(SecurityKey key)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricSignatureProvider..ctor(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean willCreateSignatures)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateSignatureProvider(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean willCreateSignatures)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateForSigning(SecurityKey key, String algorithm)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.CreateEncodedSignature(String input, SigningCredentials signingCredentials)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(SecurityToken token)
   at IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenCreationService.CreateJwtAsync(JwtSecurityToken jwt) in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\Services\DefaultTokenCreationService.cs:line 209
   at IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenCreationService.<CreateTokenAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\Services\DefaultTokenCreationService.cs:line 67
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer4.Services.DefaultTokenService.<CreateSecurityTokenAsync>d__9.MoveNext() in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\Services\DefaultTokenService.cs:line 210
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator.<CreateAccessTokenAsync>d__14.MoveNext() in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\ResponseHandling\TokenResponseGenerator.cs:line 313
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator.<ProcessAuthorizationCodeRequestAsync>d__10.MoveNext() in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\ResponseHandling\TokenResponseGenerator.cs:line 133
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGenerator.<ProcessAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\ResponseHandling\TokenResponseGenerator.cs:line 88
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint.<ProcessTokenRequestAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\Endpoints\TokenEndpoint.cs:line 98
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint.<ProcessAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\Endpoints\TokenEndpoint.cs:line 70
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\Hosting\IdentityServerMiddleware.cs:line 54
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\Hosting\IdentityServerMiddleware.cs:line 72
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\local\identity\server4\IdentityServer4\src\IdentityServer4\Hosting\BaseUrlMiddleware.cs:line 43
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
```

Comment: If you've installed it into a cert store can you run `certutil -silent -store my` and share the data for the cert (the specific one I want to know is the value for "Provider").  (`certutil -user -silent -store my` if it's in CurrentUser\My instead of LocalMachine\My)

Comment: @bartonjs Here is the output:
-------------
Serial Number: b3eeb248fd720d0e
Issuer: CN=abaris.no
 NotBefore: 16.10.2018 16:25
 NotAfter: 13.10.2028 16:25
Subject: CN=abaris.no
Signature matches Public Key
Root Certificate: Subject matches Issuer
Cert Hash(sha1): bb 1a b6 b9 f8 1b 27 07 93 92 64 bc c5 90 c3 43 d2 62 72 9c
  Key Container = {700D6BDE-4203-418B-A353-0BFEABAC26A7}
  Provider = Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0
Missing stored keyset
Encryption test passed
--------------
It also says "Missing stored keyset".....

Comment: okay, the Enhanced provider should definitely load in CNG, but the native side agreeing the private key file is missing seems indicative. When you added it to the store you probably didn’t set `PersistKeySey` and the key got deleted. For loading it from bytes, there must be some sort of key cloning going on which results in deleting the key before it gets loaded. If you re-import into the store after loading with PersistKeySet, the problem will likely go away.

Comment: @bartonjs 
I have used different settings for X509KeyStorageFlags including PersistKeySet.
When the Pfx is installed to X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser), I have verified that the private key is written to disk and that the process identity have read-write access to both folder and private key file.
When pfx is installed in MMC the certificate UI states "You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate".
I have not tried reimport as you suggests

Comment: @bartonjs I have generated another certicate with makecert, and this certificate is now successfully loading with private keys with no changes to source code.
Hence, it seems there is something with the certificate and pfx generated with OpenSSL. I am happy with using makecert for now even if it is officially deprecated.

Comment: Huh.  If you can produce a PFX that you can share that has that symptom, I'd love to get my hands on one and see what's wrong with it.

Comment: @bartonjs Yes, I will. Need a couple of days to catch up with some other work.

Answer (score 59):

The problem was resolved by adding IIS_IUSR group.
From this link [Add group IIS_IUSR](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/6840):

The problem was that the Permissions for the Private Key of the Certificate in the Windows Certificate Store did not have the IIS_IUSRS group set to allow read access.

Right click certificate -> All Tasks -> Manage Private Keys -> Add group "IIS_IUSRS"

Comment: In my case, my `Application Pool Identity` is not IIS_IUSR, but this answer still solved my problem; adding the identity of the App Pool to the Permissions for the private key fixed it.  Thank you!

Comment: This solution will vary and as @codeMonkey noted was a different application pool identity.  Mine was a completely different app user.  Check your app for more details - adding iis_usr might not work for you.

Comment: Adding `IIS_IUSRS` group to certificate worked for me even if I have a different application pool identity. +1

Comment: We have had this problem for months and this fixed it. Thank you all.

Comment: @mihuilk you are a god among programmers, thank you!

Comment: After doing this, I got the same exception. But running Visual Studio as Administrator was the solution.

Comment: In my case, I was using Kestrel and instead of IIS_IUSRS, I had to add LocalService to have access to read the cert private key

Answer (score 14):

I followed that blog post too and also had that issue.
The problem was when you run this to create PKCS12 file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out example.pfx -inkey example.key -in example.crt -certfile example.crt
```

Try to remove `-certfile example.crt` and it should work.

Also according to [.NET Core X509Certificate2 usage (under Windows/IIS, Docker, Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53334142/net-core-x509certificate2-usage-under-windows-iis-docker-linux) you can test if certificate was loaded from file correctly by accessing `cert.PrivateKey`.
E.g.

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "cert.pfx"), "password");
Console.WriteLine("cert private key: " + cert.PrivateKey);
```

Comment: Why does this work? Removing `-certfile example.crt` solved the problem. But it seems the pfx created is smaller without the last command, but with the last command, it does not contain a private key?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but as I understand ```-certfile file``` options allows to add a chain of certificates (adds all certificates in that file to the .p12 store in addition to the input certificate)

Answer (score 7):

On IIS 10 I had to change my app pool identity to LocalSystem

Answer (score 3):

Oh hey, that's my blog post! Glad to see that it's... well hopefully helping despite problems people run into. Speaking of which I have now run into this exception myself!

My problem was that I created the certificate and tried to load it from disk using the `new X509Certificate2(path, password)` syntax, but for some reason I had to import the cert into the registry on my development machine to stop the exception from occuring. I'm not actually sure why.

Make sure to import the certificate to the `My/Personal` store of the `CurrentUser` registry.

There are so many different answers on this thread, I hope one of them works for you, reader :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, which by the way wasn't an API but a class library, I just had to make sure I was running visual studio in admin mode and that this user I was opening the visual studio with, was the same one who had the certificate installed in the store/mmc. Reach out if any question.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was really bringing me grief because none of the above solutions were helping.

Here's what it was:
https://improveandrepeat.com/2018/12/how-to-fix-the-keyset-does-not-exist-cryptographicexception/

I needed to go to mmc, add the Certificates snap-in, select the cert, go to All Tasks > Manage Private Keys, and add the IIS_IUSRS (or specific app pool if you prefer). I had tried doing something similar in certmgr.msc but for whatever reason the Manage Private Keys option was not available under All Tasks from that area.

Answer (score 0):

On **IIS** application pools select the application then **advanced settings** and set Identity: Localsystem and Load user profile: true
[image]