# IdentityServer 4 Authentication Failure

Tags: asp.net-core

This is my first time deploying to a production server. Everything worked fine on my development machine until I deployed to production.

I keep getting the following error message "....keyset does not exist"

and did some digging and one of the solutions was to grant access to IIS_IUSRS to the private key as prescribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52851399/windowscryptographicexception-keyset-does-not-exist).

Since I dont have that level of access to the server where my app is deployed how do I do this?

Comment: Now most of the solutions are as mentioned in this article, need permissions to add the IIS_IUSR group to solve the problem.

Comment: This is the response from my Service providers `Unfortunately, we are not expertise on assisting web developement issues. We can only check if there is an issue on the server end. As per the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52851399/windowscryptographicexception-keyset-does-not-exist if you would like to add permission to IIS_IUSR group it is not possible on shared hosting.`

Comment: @Chaodeng So what options do I have?