# Shared Hosting Enviroment, IIS_IUSRS and permissions

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an app hosted in a shared environment. During the login process from domain A to Domain B, I get the error below `Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: Keyset does not exist` 
I did some research online (StackOverflow) and the solution prescribed largely dwelt around ISS_IUSRS permissions.
I contacted my service providers and they basically told me I am on my own Below is the response:
`"Unfortunately, we are not experts on assisting web development issues. We can only check if there is an issue on the server end. As per the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52851399/windowscryptographicexception-keyset-does-not-exist if you would like to add permission to IIS_IUSR group it is not possible on shared hosting."`
How do I get past this problem in a shared hosting environment?

Comment: It sounds like their hosting does not support changing `IUSR` so it seems like you are at a dead end with these hosts. You know you can get your own VM on Azure from $71 a year

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDemaid. Need more info on this. can you guide along?

Comment: This is a very broad question, you could look into VM's on public clouds like AWS/Azure/Google Cloud. Another option would be to hire a VPS by for example digitalocean.